# Calling a controller action MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok so I got action that is in controller and code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveRow(int? id)
{
    //some db operations.
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and in view I got

```
@Html.ActionLink(Translation.Accept, "SaveRow", new { id = item.New.RecId })
```

I got error 404 when I click button is possible to run this action without redirecting to `url /SaveRow/` ?
Maybe this button is used wrong I'm new in mvc5 so be patient.

Comment: Links are `GET`, you have marked the method as `POST`. Use [a form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590(v=vs.118).aspx) to reach it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/aspnet/bPTF281212-Difference-between-HttpGet-and-HttpPost-Method.html) :-

> 2.An hyperlink or anchor tag that points to an action will ALWAYS be an HttpGet.

Try below code putting GET, as by default it takes `[HttpGet]` so remove `[HttpPost]` attribute

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SaveRow(int? id)
{
    //some db operations.
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and as an ideal design of MVC I would suggest you to use `@Html.BeginForm` to access pertiular `POST` call of edit functionailty

Comment: Using [HttpGet] - think you missed that from the code.

Comment: by default it takes [HttpGet] @RyanMcDonough

Comment: Always worth adding so you can see at a glance, aslo you can override the default so if that happened it would still be GET.

Comment: Its intranet ;) @GSerg

Comment: @Neel Thx at all my hope this will help more ppl then me;)